# How to add a new pair of key(str) and value(list) and append an int in the value list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I have the following code. I can't find the way of creating a new key and append a number to the value list.

```
from typing import Dict, List, Set

diccionary: Dict[str, List[int]]
diccionary = {}

diccionary["key"].append(2)
diccionary["key2"].append(4)
diccionary["key2"].append(1)

print(diccionary)
```

When I run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diccionario.py", line 5, in <module>
    diccionario["key"].append(2)
KeyError: 'key'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
diccionary = {}
diccionary.setdefault("key", []).append(2)
diccionary.setdefault("key2", []).append(4)
diccionary.setdefault("key2", []).append(1)

print(diccionary)
```

Or, use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

diccionary = defaultdict(list)

diccionary["key"].append(2)
diccionary["key2"].append(4)
diccionary["key2"].append(1)

print(dict(diccionary))
```

Output:

```
{'key': [2], 'key2': [4, 1]}
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is exactly the answer for this. Good thing that python has 'batteries included'.